Issue with Variable Assignments in Parallel ForEach Loop in Azure Data Factory for Incremental Load
I have variables declared inside a ForEach loop in Azure Data Factory, and they are being assigned sequentially. The values stored in these variables are used for incremental loading, specifically to store watermark values to track data changes.
When I run the loop sequentially, the variable assignments work as expected. However, when I switch to running the loop in parallel, the variable assignments don't behave as expected. It seems like the variables are receiving incorrect values because of the parallel execution.
Has anyone encountered similar issues when using variables in a parallel ForEach loop in Azure Data Factory? How can I ensure that the correct values are assigned to the variables, even when the loop runs in parallel?

Verified that variables are declared and initialized correctly within the loop.
Ensured the loop is set to run in parallel.
Checked the logic for how the variables are being used for incremental loading.

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!


How can I ensure that the correct values are assigned to the variables, even when the loop runs in parallel?

In parallel execution, the iterations are not dependent on each iteration and each iteration won't wait till the completion of the previous iterations.
You can go through the below demo for better understanding.
First, I have declared an array variable arr and given values like [1,2,3,4]. I have given this array to a for-each activity and set the execution in parallel.

Inside the loop, I have used append variable activity to append each item value to the array test and I have displayed the array after the for-each activity. Each iteration will take values from the given array and will be completed at random.
You can see the order of the result array after the for-loop is not same as the first array.

In this, the iteration order is not fixed, and it is random. It is the same reason why you got the above results.
In the case of incremental loading where the current iteration depends on the values of the previous iteration or fixed order of iterations, the parallel execution of the for-each activity will not work. You need the for-each activity execution to be in a Sequential manner in this case. The parallel execution can be used when the iteration or the results of those iterations are independent to each other.
In the same example, it will give expected results when the loop was executed in a Sequential manner.

